# DotNetNuke: How to add paging to the core announcements module

Tags: dotnetnuke, paging

**Situation looks like this:**

I need to add paging to [the core announcement module](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/Module-Announcements.aspx) in [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke). My client is adding more and more announcements and now the page is too long. I am using the announcements module for news.

**The problem:** 
The announcements module does not have a paging system. Is there any way to add a paging system to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Announcements module is missing lots of key features. I'd recommend switching from it to one of the many Articles modules available.

- [Ventrian News Articles](http://www.ventrian.com/Products/Modules/NewsArticles.aspx) -
  probably the most popular
- [DNN Simple
  Article](http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/) - New, free, and open
  source, built by a core team member
- [Efficion's Articles Module](http://www.efficionconsulting.com/dotnetnuke/modules/articles) - My
  favorite, but then I built it

There are lots of other options out there as well.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Ventrian News Articles.